# resize2fs: New size too large to be expressed in 32 bits

Tags: linux, ubuntu, resize

I had a 12TB ext4 partition which I wanted to extend to 18TB. I've added the new disks to the RAID and after doing that I wanted to re-size the partition to occupy this new space. I started the growth of the partition but the procedure failed because the ext4 cannot handle partitions bigger than 16TB.

The problem is that now when I open gparted, gparted shows that the size of the partition is 18TB but I can see only 12TB in Nautilus window.

How can I roll back the effects of the gparted operation so the two sizes are consistent with each other?

```
# resize2fs /dev/sda1

resize2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
resize2fs: New size too large to be expressed in 32 bits
```

Comment: os: ububtu 14.04

Comment: Try running fsck on the partition

Comment: I try to fix it by fsck, but it‘s not effective.

Comment: Try with e2fsck. It is more specific to ext4 filesystems

Comment: Thanks,i will try it.

Comment: resize2fs defaults to **expanding** the filesystem.  If you want to **shrink** it, you'll have to read the *fine manual*.

Answer (score 6):

What you apparently really want is not to roll back your changes, but to be able to resize your file system to a size greater than the 16TB limit.

For that, you need a version of e2fsprogs >= 1.43 and then activate 64bit support with the `-b` switch of `resize2fs`. If yo have an older Ubuntu with e2fsprogs 1.42 or older, you can find [backports of e2fsprogs in the Launchpad PPAs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=e2fsprogs) or compile it from source.

Once you have a recent enough version of e2fsprogs:

```
umount       /dev/$YOUR_DISK
e2fsck -f    /dev/$YOUR_DISK
resize2fs -b /dev/$YOUR_DISK
e2fsck -f    /dev/$YOUR_DISK
mount ...
```

See [this answer for more details](https://askubuntu.com/a/779755/8822).

Comment: I'm seeing a few distributions have a version of `e2fsprogs` at or greater than 1.43, but the information here is still very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't forget to expand the filesystem with the -p option, after the system has been converted to 64-bit, as explained [in the link cited by Mivk](https://askubuntu.com/a/779755/8822).

```
umount       /dev/$YOUR_DISK
e2fsck -f    /dev/$YOUR_DISK
resize2fs -b /dev/$YOUR_DISK    # Enable 64bit support in the filesystem
resize2fs -p /dev/$YOUR_DISK    # Resize the filesystem
e2fsck -f    /dev/$YOUR_DISK
mount ...
```